# Physical and mathematical relation between $(\tau, \sigma)$ parameters and coordinates $X^\mu$ in String Theory

Tags: coordinate-systems, string-theory, definition, boundary-conditions

When we define the parameter space for a string Worldsheet $\Sigma$ to be diffeomorphic to, say, $\mathbb{R} \times [0,1]$ or $\mathbb{R}\times S^1$, and use standard coordinates $(\tau, \sigma)$, $\sigma \sim \sigma +2\pi$ for the closed string case, I usually have some doubts:

1. What are the properties of the coordinates ($\tau, \sigma)$ that does not depend on the embedding $X(\tau, \sigma)$ we choose at first? For instance, I think that for each $\tau$ the points $(\tau, 0), (\tau, 1) \in \partial \Sigma$ should be mapped to respective boundary points in $\partial X(\Sigma)$ to be the *physical* endpoints of an open string. Are there other implications?
2. Besides that, what is the relation between the $\tau$ coordinate and the time $X^0(\tau, \sigma)$? Most of textbooks obtain equations of motion treating thing on the $\Sigma$ domain without specifying to much about the image $X(\Sigma)$ : if the strings are the portions of $X(\Sigma)$ with fixed value $X^0 = x^0$, why do we care *only* about the "time interval" $[\tau_0, \tau_1]$ when varying the action, if there is no guarantee that the values $\tau_0, \tau_1$ correspond to actual instants of time in the ambient space?